# Solving the inequality using Binomial Theorem

Tags: binomial-theorem, holder-inequality

I had to prove the following inequality

$$a^{3/5}b^{2/5}\leq 3a/5+2b/5$$

For real and non negative a and b

I was able to prove it using Holder’s inequality and also AM-GM inequality. I need to know if can be done just by using the binomial theorem. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: It may help you to know that this is a special case of Young's inequality: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Young%27s_inequality_for_products

Comment: If there is a way, you are going to need something addition. You want to show $$(3a+2b)^5= 243 a^5 + 810 a^4 b + 1080 a^3 b^2 + 720 a^2 b^3 + 240 a b^4 + 32 b^5\geq 5^5a^3b^2.$$ This can be rewritten: $$243 (a^5-a^3b^2) + 810( a^4 b-a^3b^2)  + 720 (a^2 b^3-b^2) + 240( a b^4 -a^3b^2) + 32 (b^5-a^3b^2)\geq 0$$ Seems like you will need some other inequality here.

Answer (score -1):

Per your question, the answer is **no**. Here is another approach which is already mentioned in the comment line. But I still post it here to remind you about the concavity of log. The function $f(x) = \ln x $ in concave $ \implies \dfrac{3}{5}\ln a + \dfrac{2}{5}\ln b \le \ln\left(\dfrac{3}{5}a+\dfrac{2}{5}b\right)$. Can you finish it ?

Comment: Is there a reasoning that I can give to say that a proof with binomial theorem is not possible?